# что значит i или i++ в js

Tags: javascript

изучаю уже 2 день и нe понимаю что значит i

Comment: `i` – просто популярное название переменной. `++` – [оператор инкремента](https://learn.javascript.ru/operators#inkrement-dekrement). Откройте любой учебник и изучайте, это же самые основы.

Comment: уже 2 день:) http://learn.javascript.ru/ надеюсь здесь изучаете

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Скорее всего увидели в цикле фор, так i это переменная, а і++ это увеличение числа в переменной на 1 при каждой итерации цикла